# Is there a way to use Kotlinx serialisation in an Android savedInstanceState Bundle?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, bundle, kotlinx

It looks like the compiler doesn't want to use Kotlinx serialized classes in `putSerializable` and `getSerializable`.
It says `Type mismatch: inferred type is MyViewModel.SavedState but Serializable? was expected`.

In my Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout)

    viewModel.init(savedInstanceState?.getSerializable(SAVE_STATE) as? SavedState) // compiler complains here
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putSerializable(SAVE_STATE, viewModel.buildSaveState()) // and here
}
```

In my ViewModel:

```
fun buildSaveState(): SavedState =
        SavedState(value1, value2, value3, value4)

@Serializable
data class SavedState(val foo: Boolean?,
                      val foo1: Enum1?,
                      val foo2: Enum2?,
                      val foo3: MyType?)
```

MyType:

```
@Serializable
sealed class MyType {
    data class MyType1(val foo4: Enum3) : MyType()
    data class MyType2(val foo5: Enum4) : MyType()

    enum class Enum3 {
        ...
    }

    enum class Enum4 {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Kotlinx.Serialization is not OOB compatible with Bundle's putSerializable. However, you could just `stringify` your `SavedState`, send it via `putString` and on the receiving end deserialize string back to your class.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I used `Json.stringify(serializer, value)` and `Json.parse(serializer, value)` by passing in the serializer class (type `KSerializer<T>`) obtained from `SavedState.serializer()`.

I also had to add `@Serializable` to each of the subclasses in the sealed class.

Comment: Wheres the stringify function coming from? I cant fint it on my Json object from kotlinx.serialization.json. Has it been renamed to encodeToString?

Comment: Yes, Kotlinx.serialization uses encodeToString and decodeFromString for serialization/deserialization.